# How to sum columns by two groups, then collapse the rows in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I've done a bunch of searching but can't figure out exactly how to do this. Hopefully someone here can help.

I have a data frame in R represented below: `

```
  year id soak pots week fleet
1 2009 42    4   20    1  cr23
2 2009 42    3   15    1  cr23
3 2009 42    4   20    1  cr23
4 2010 42    3   15    1  cr23
5 2010 42    3   15    1  cr23
6 2010 42    3   65    1  cr23
```

What I want to do is to end up with a new (smaller) data frame or data table that:
1) adds up the 'pots' column for each 'id', 'week', and 'year'.
2) averages the 'soak' column for each 'id', 'week', and 'year'.
3) keeps the 'fleet' and 'id' values (which don't vary across week and year) in the new data frame (although I only need 1 value for these variables for each row).

Any ideas? I'm sure there is a way to do this in data.table but I can't figure it out so far.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `data.table`:

```
setDT(DF)
DF[ , .(pots = sum(pots), soak = mean(soak)),
   by = .(id, week, year, fleet, id)]
```

Since you're sure `fleet` and `id` are unchanged within `id`x`week`x`year`, we can add them to `by` without changing anything.

Alternative is to add them to `j` and exclude them from `by`:

```
.(pots = sum(pots), soak = mean(soak), fleet = fleet[1L], id = id[1L])
```

Comment: This works really well. Thanks! For some reason I have a lot of trouble understanding how to use data.table even though i've been trying to figure it out for a while.

Comment: @user1754348 it's never a bad idea to [go through the Getting Started guide](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

This gets you started

```
library(dplyr)
your.data %>%
  group_by(id, week, year) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(pots))
```